# How can I make Autowired adnotation working?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autowired

I'm trying to learn spring using some internet courses. I have problem with @Autowired and I'm still getting Error: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

I have found many similar problems, but no one suits mine.

My Product class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class Product {

@Id
private int id;
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String desc;
private double price;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

Interface ProductRepository:

```
import HIB_UD_01.product.entities.Product;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product,    Integer> {
}
```

ProductdataApplication:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductdataApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ProductdataApplication.class, args);

}

}
```

And my Test class:

```
import HIB_UD_01.product.entities.Product;
import HIB_UD_01.product.repos.ProductRepository;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProductdataApplicationTests {

@Autowired
ProductRepository repository;

@Test
public void contextLoads() {
}

@Test
public void testCreate() {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId(1);
    product.setName("Iphone");
    product.setDesc("Awesome");
    product.setPrice(1000d);
    repository.save(product);
}

}
```

And last,my properites file:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=password
```

I should put data about product into db, but I get an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'HIB_UD_01.product.ProductdataApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'HIB_UD_01.product.repos.ProductRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Read the error again perticularly about ProductRepository `expressed through field 'repository'; ` and hope you will get what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to enable repositories on your SpringBootApplication class (or in a separate configuration class):
https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-crudrepository-example

If that doesn't work, make sure your SpringBootApplication class is a package higher then the rest of your classes, so SpringBoot can autodetect your beans. (And you can try to annotate your repository with @Repository then, to make sure SpringBoot autodetects your repository.)

Also see:
https://dzone.com/articles/the-springbootapplication-annotation-example-in-ja
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem fixed. I added @Repository to ProductRepository. I cleared repository folder and download new fresh repositories. 
Then I have error with time zone in connection to MySQL. So I edit my properities file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Thank you for your help!